# Ninject and Custom Controller Factory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject, mef

I'm using MEF with ASP.NET MVC as demonstrated at http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/06/17/Revised-ASPNET-MVC-and-the-Managed-Extensibility-Framework-(MEF).aspx.

When I try to use Ninject, it seems that nothing gets injected. I did some debugging, and when I reverted to the original controller factory the injection worked.

What needs to be changed, or what does Ninject need in terms of controller factories for it to work?

Comment: Have you tried the Ninject Google Group? http://groups.google.com/group/ninject?pli=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Nate Kohari's Ninject.Web.MVC project on GitHub](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc). It's makes Ninject integration with ASP.NET MVC projects extremely easy.