# Stuck Working Through Steven Sanderson's "ASP.NET MVC 2..."

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, ninject

I received a brief introduction to ASP.NET MVC in school and I am trying to expand that knowledge base with Steven Sanderson's book *Pro ASP.NET MVC 2 Framework*.  It's been a great help, but I have hit a wall in the example that implements Ninject.  I believe the DI is setup correctly, but when I try to specify the bindings for a dependency in my Ninject controller class, I receive one of two brown screens of death:

***No parameterless constructor defined for this object.***

Stack Trace:

```
[MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +98
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +241
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +69
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +6
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +491

[InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'SportsStore.WebUI.Controllers.ProductsController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +628
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +204
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +193
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +160
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +80
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +45
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8898152
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184
```

***Object reference not set to an instance of an object.***

Stack Trace:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   SportsStore.WebUI.Infrastructure.SportsStoreServices.Load() in D:\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CSharp2010AndDotNet4PlatformBook\SportsStore\SportsStore.WebUI\Infrastructure\NinjectControllerFactory.cs:33
   Ninject.Modules.NinjectModule.OnLoad(IKernel kernel) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Modules\NinjectModule.cs:60
   Ninject.KernelBase.Load(IEnumerable`1 modules) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\KernelBase.cs:222
   Ninject.KernelBase..ctor(IComponentContainer components, INinjectSettings settings, INinjectModule[] modules) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\KernelBase.cs:102
   Ninject.KernelBase..ctor(INinjectModule[] modules) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\KernelBase.cs:57
   Ninject.StandardKernel..ctor(INinjectModule[] modules) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\StandardKernel.cs:31
   SportsStore.WebUI.Infrastructure.NinjectControllerFactory..ctor() in D:\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CSharp2010AndDotNet4PlatformBook\SportsStore\SportsStore.WebUI\Infrastructure\NinjectControllerFactory.cs:18
   SportsStore.WebUI.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in D:\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CSharp2010AndDotNet4PlatformBook\SportsStore\SportsStore.WebUI\Global.asax.cs:32
```

Here is my code in the Ninject controller class:

```
public class NinjectControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    // A Ninject "kernel" is the things that can supply object instances
    private IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new SportsStoreServices());

    // ASP.NET MVC calls this to get the controller for each request
    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext context, Type controllerType)
    {
        if (controllerType == null)
            return null;
        return (IController)kernel.Get(controllerType);
    }

    // Configures how abstract service types are mapped to concrete implementations
    private class SportsStoreServices : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<IProductsRepository>()
                .To<SqlProductsRepository>()
                .WithConstructorArgument("connectionString",
                    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppDb"].ConnectionString
                    );
        }
    }
}
```

The book is pushing up against the limits of my understanding, but I am following along and have been able to debug everything up to this point.  This has me stumped.  Any idea where I would begin to debug this?

Comment: does this happen every single time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both issues are related to Ninject not being setup or integrated correctly.  The trunk version of Ninject allows you to bypass having to define custom controller factories.  It's a cleaner setup and less confusing.

See:

- http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2009/08/14/how-to-use-ninject-2-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx

Additionally you should check out the article listed here

- [Ninject and Custom Controller Factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459770/ninject-and-custom-controller-factory)

Comment: Thanks for the starting point.  It's good to know what to pursue.  I'd vote your answer up, but apprently I don't have the necessary reputation!

Comment: @Midloo One of your problems could be due to your current version of Ninject requiring each controller to have a default constructor with no parameters defined 'public MyController(){}'.  However I don't recall that this should be necessary, you should find that if you use a newer version of Ninject you'll get it working quicker.

Comment: Thanks for the further tip.  I am working with the latest release, v2.2.0.0 for .NET 4.0.  The book is working from v.2.0 targeting .NET 3.5.  Could be part of my issue as well.  Thanks again for your direction.  It kept some hairs in my head.

Comment: Ninject does not require parameterless constructors. But as Justin said. Why do you use your own implementation when there is a working one? The stacktraces show that the controller factory has not been replaced properly. And the second one that your conncetion string configuration returns null.

Comment: @Remo Thanks for your comment. The book recommended creating your own implementation so that you have an understanding of how to use DI containers other than Ninject. Seemed like good logic at the time, but the Ninject MVC extension does make this easier. I do need more work on making sense of the stack traces. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1):

Did you update your application_start in global.asax to point to the ninject controller factory?

as such:

```
protected void Application_Start() {
..........

  ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new NinjectControllerFactory ());
}
```